# How to generate serial number and after edit add new record with sub-serial number in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

When creating a new quotation auto generate serial number like `AP-00-0001` but after create and edit this quotation and save again create a new entry without affecting existing quotation number or data and generate new sub quotation number like `AP-01-0001`.

### On Add Quotation:

when add new quotation generate my new number but how to write on revise quotation:

```
    $count_quot = $this->QuotationGeneration->find('count');
    $count_quot = $count_quot + 1;

    $number = str_pad($count_quot, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

    $quotation_number = 'AP-00-'.$number;

    $this->set('quotation_number',$quotation_number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the beforeSave() or afterSave() callback of your table object and generate your number there.

- https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforesave
- https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#aftersave

Or look at the code of this behavior. It pretty much does the same just that it generates a slug. https://github.com/UseMuffin/Slug